# Mark duplicate for each column

Tags: excel, vba

is there any VBA code to highlight duplicate values in each columns?
The file have thousands of columns, I need to check each columns if any duplicate values and mark them.
I can manual check each column by using "Conditional Formatting->duplicate values

[image: sample of the file,], but took so many time.

I've tried using "Conditional Formatting->duplicate values

Comment: What is your interest.? Duplication anywhere within the column or just if the next column value is a duplicate? It looks like you want the latter.

Comment: Are the columns always sorted ? With other words: Will duplicate values are always be in the next row(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional formatting, but with a formula.
Mark all cells of your sheet and create the conditional formatting with the formula

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1
```

The function `CountIf` counts the number of cells in a range (1st parameter, "A":A") that have a specific value (2nd parameter, "A1"). Then it is checked if the value can be found more that 1 time (which means in that column a duplicate exists).

The formula will use relative references. For example, cell E7 would be calculated with `=COUNTIF(E:E,E7)>1`.

**UPDATE**
If the values of a column are always sorted and therefore same values are grouped together in adjacent rows, you can use the following formula (again for the whole sheet)

```
`=AND(A1<>"",OR(A1=A2,A1=A1048576))`
```

It looks a little bit more complicated but the calculation is faster.

Comment: Good approach but OP said *thousands of columns** so referencing full columns thousands of times may overcharge calculations.

Comment: Tested with 3000 rows and 3000 columns of data: Took < 1s, and my computer is not very powerfull.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: Updated with a faster solution if the columns are sorted.

Comment: Thank you, is there any code ... Seems I can't run above macro by Ike. btw, it's not so duplicate, for example, in case only 1 column B, then I can manual find duplicate 4500, but there are over 3000 columns,, no need to compare column B with column C. but columns always sorted

Comment: No, there is no code. This is pure Excel, simply set a conditional formatting, but not with "duplicate values", but with a formula (*"Use a formula to determine which cells for format"*)

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the duplicates per column you can use this sub - you have to pass e.g. `ActiveSheet.Range("B6")`

```vb
Sub formatDuplicatesPerColumn(rg As Range)

Dim c As Range, uv As UniqueValues

With rg.CurrentRegion
    For Each c In .Columns
        With c.FormatConditions
            .Delete
            Set uv = .AddUniqueValues
            With uv
                .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
                .Interior.Color = 13551615
            End With
        End With
    Next
End With
            
End Sub
```